# SQL Server Insert Null error in spite of providing not null values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do an insert but it is giving an error stating that credits cannot be null but I am not providing null. [Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XBTV.png)

Code:  Insert into [dbo].[Course] values (12,'Java',1,1,1);

Error: Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure trgAfterInsert, Line 31
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Credits', table 'DemoCollege.dbo.Course'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Trigger:

```
Create trigger trgAfterInsert2 ON [dbo].[Course]
After Insert
AS 
Declare @cid int;
Declare @cname nvarchar(50);



Select @cid = i.CourseID from inserted i;
Select @cname = i.Title from inserted i;


Insert into dbo.CourseTemp values (@cid, @cname);

Print 'After insert trigger fired';
GO
```

Comment: You have a failing trigger on the table

Comment: Always provide column list in insert statement.

Comment: And please note that your trigger does not support multiple row inserts.

Comment: There's no way that trigger generates the error you're getting. Please post the actual one.

Answer (score 2):

There's an insert trigger on the table & that's where the error is being generated from.
There must be some logic in that is converting the provided credit value to a null value somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the columns where you want to insert the values.

```
 Insert into [dbo].[Course](ColName1, ColName2, ColName3, ColName4, etc..) values (12,'Java',1,1,1);
```

Most probably you're missing a col in the middle

Comment: Good advice to provide column list, but it's not the problem here.